# Reload ajaxsource in jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I m using jquery dataTable with serverside processing data. i m using asp.net web method for serverside processing. I have 2 web methode lets called it 'WebMethod1' and 'WebMethod2' and 2 buttons 'Button1' and 'Button2' when i click Button1 i want to call data from WebMethod1 and when i click Button2 i want to call data from WebMethod2

HTML

```
<button type="button" class="data-search" data-Get="Members" id="btnMemberSearch">Button1</button>
<button type="button" class="data-search" data-Get="Accounts" id="btnAccountSearch">Button1</button>
<table class="table table-hover" style="width:100%;" id="tblSearchList">
   <thead id="tblSearchHead">
   </thead>
</table>
```

Jquery

```
var columns='';
var tr=''; 
var functionName ='';
$(".member-search").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var searchfor = $(this).attr('data-Get');
    if (searchfor == 'Members') {
        tr = '<tr><th>MemberNo</th><th>Name</th><th>FatherName</th><th>Mobile</th><th>CitizenshipNo</th></tr>';
        functionName = 'WebMethod1';
        columns = [
        { data: "MemberNo" },
        { data: "Name" },
        { data: "FatherName" },
        { data: "Mobile" },
        { data: "CitizenshipNo" }];
    }
    else if (searchfor == 'Accounts) {
        tr = '<tr><th>AccountNo</th><th>Name</th><th>MemberNo</th><th>Product</th></tr>';
        functionName = 'WebMethod2';
        columns = [{ data: "AccountNo" },
            { data: "Name" },
            { data: "MemberNo" },
            {data:"Product"}
        ]
    }
    $('#tblSearchHead').children().remove();
    $('#tblSearchHead').append(tr);
    ajaxSource = '../Main/MemAndAcSearch.asmx/'+functionName;
    table = $('#tblSearchList').DataTable({
        bServerSide: true,
        retrieve: true,
        columns:columns,
        sAjaxSource: ajaxSource,
        sServerMethod: 'post',
        bProcessing: true
        }
    });
});
```

Here the problem is ajaxsource is not being refreshed or reloaded.After loading the page same Webmethod from the button that i clicked 1st is called until i reload the page. e.g After loading page If i click Button1 then WebMethod1 is called for every time even though i click Button2 and if i reload the page a click Button2 then WebMethod2 is called every time now.

How can i reload my ajax source.?

Answer (score 0):

Change the button id's since for DOM id's play crucial role in creating and manipulating DOM.

```
<button type="button" class="data-search" data-Get="Members" id="btnNomineeAcMembersSearch">Button1</button>
<button type="button" class="data-search" data-Get="Accounts" id="btnNomineeAcSearch">Button2</button>
```

Comment: sorry my mistake it was actually different. That was not a problem